# Sending # symbol with AJAX to PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I have got this Ajax that send comment's text to PHP

```
       $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '../files/ajax.php',
            data: "C=" + cc+"&I="+i,
            success:function(data) {
                alert(data);
          }
         });

if (isset($_GET["I"]) && isset($_GET["C"])) {
    $RandS=$_GET["I"];
    $Comment=$_GET["C"];
    $Comment=trim($_GET["C"]);
    $Comment=htmlspecialchars($_GET["C"]);
   echo $Comment;
 }
```

When comment is something like
`Hope you like pancakes` It returns everything perfectly,But when comment is `'#I #Like pancakes'` it does not return anything except error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the sending, I think it's with the receiving. For some reason the AJAX call is assuming the server returns JSON which it doesn't.

Comment: It does return JSON.I just did not give the whole code @apokryfos

Comment: @apokryfos That sounds right, although it doesn't explain why it works when the comment doesn't have `#` characters.

Comment: It's probably something to do with how you json encode the result that's messing up. Can you show us?

Comment: If you don't show the correct code, how do you expect us to figure out what's wrong? The problem could be in something you left out.

Comment: @Barmar but you have already found the answer

Comment: I don't understand why the answer I gave would solve that error. As @apokryfos said, that error is related to processing the JSON response, not sending the parameters to the scdript.

Comment: Json returns what i need when data i sent have no "#" in it. @Barmar

Comment: If you call `json_encode()` before echoing, it shouldn't matter what's in the data. The problem I identified has to do with sending the parameters, not returning it.

Comment: @Barmar then problem is in sending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to URL-encode the parameters if they contain special characters. When using `$.ajax`, the best way to ensure that they're encoded properly is to use an object rather than a string for the `data:` option.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '../files/ajax.php',
    data: { C: cc, I: i },
    success:function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```